# Is the Pentaho Web service complete?

Tags: rest, olap, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I want to build RESTful web service for communicate between Pentaho (Mondrian) and my application on Windows 8 Tablet (Javascript) and I found this site http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-cws/ but when I try to use the code in this project it seem like it is not complete yet. Does anyone ever try it? if it work, how you try it? or this project is not complete? Is it still in developing progress?

If you have any effective way to build web service for Pentaho (Mondrian) please give me a suggestion.

I heard that Saiku have a REST web service. Is that can help me in this step?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

The Saiku web service might indeed be the way to go. It has a well documented (via enunciate) API that is part of every Saiku installation.

For example, the for the Saiku running at http://demo.analytical-labs.com/ has a [web services documentation](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/serverdocs/) and a [list of all REST resources](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/serverdocs/rest.html).

If the man goal is to run MDX queries (without a query model), then the XMLA interface of Mondrian could be the easier alternative: http://business-intelligence.phi-integration.com/2008/04/testing-mondrian-as-xmla-provider.html.

Comment: Saiku is definately the way to go - but if you do want to roll your own then also take a look at olap4j.